# How to join two spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 spark RDD, the 1st one contains a mapping between some indices and ids which are strings and the 2nd one contains tuples of related indices

```
val ids = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array[(Int, String)](
      (1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d"), (5, "e"))).toDF("index", "idx")


val relationships = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array[(Int, Int)](
  (1, 3), (2, 3), (4, 5))).toDF("index1", "index2")
```

I want to join somehow these RDD (or merge or sql or any best spark practice) to have at the end related ids instead:

The result of my combined RDD should return:

```
("a", "c"), ("b", "c"), ("d", "e")
```

Any idea how I can achieve this operation in an optimal way without loading any of the RDD into a memory map (because in my scenarios, these RDD can potentially load millions of records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this by creating a two `views` from `DataFrame` as following

```
relationships.createOrReplaceTempView("relationships");
ids.createOrReplaceTempView("ids");
```

Next run the following SQL query to generate the required result which performs inner join between `relationships` and `ids` view to generate the required result

```
import sqlContext.sql;
val result = spark.sql("""select t.index1, id.idx from 
                                (select id.idx as index1, rel.index2 
                               from relationships rel
                               inner join
                               ids id on rel.index1=id.index) t
                         inner join
                         ids id
                         on id.index=t.index2
                      """);

result.show()
```

Another approach using `DataFrame` without creating `views`

```
relationships.as("rel").
join(ids.as("ids"),  $"ids.index" === $"rel.index1").as("temp").
join(ids.as("ids"), $"temp.index2"===$"ids.index").
select($"temp.idx".as("index1"), $"ids.idx".as("index2")).show
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go and see if this work. Alternatively, my original issue which I wanted to solve: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046919/convert-to-rdd-with-original-id-after-computing-matrix-column-similarities) if you have any other idea

Comment: I have updated the other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046919/convert-to-rdd-with-original-id-after-computing-matrix-column-similarities if you have any idea